# Allegrograph import rdf file failed

Tags: import, rdf, allegrograph

I've got this error when i import a rdf file into AllegroGrahp:

```
Import failed:
String does not represent a floating-point number (last character was .)
```

Where can I see the detail of error? What does that error mean ?

Comment: I'm not really an AllegroGraph user, but I expect that somewhere there was a literal like `"..."^^xsd:float` or `"..."^^xsd:double` where the `...` wasn't a floating point number.

Comment: @abent Which version of allegro graph are you using? Can you display some sample inputs?